# Create a singleton for referenced assembly

Tags: c#, dll, singleton

I have a hardware component that can be controlled via an SDK (a `.DLL` file referenced in the project).
I'm trying to implement a helper class that will handle the instantiation of the object and will serve the required `object reference` to each window that will require it.
This is how I create the object in the code behind of the window:

```
    //private fields
    SystemConnector myConn; 
    MyHardware mySystem; // this is the object i need a reference to

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemDiscoverer SystemDiscoverer = new SystemDiscoverer();
        SystemDiscoverer.Discovered += (sysInfo) =>
        {
            myConn = new SystemConnector(sysInfo.IPAddress);

            if (myConn != null)
                mySystem = new MyHardware(myConn);

        };
        SystemDiscoverer.Discover();
    }

    private void WindowBase_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myConn != null)
            myConn.Dispose();

        if (mySystem != null)
            mySystem.Dispose();
    }
```

I want to move this logic into a helper class but I have some questions I couldn't find a solution for:

- all of the Singleton examples I could find were for custom objects
  and did not explain the use of a referenced object.
- How to handle
  the creation of the object since it's done inside of an event handler?

Comment: Does the event `SystemDiscoverer.Discovered` trigger after calling `SystemDiscoverer.Discover()`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

To handle the creation from an event handler, try:

```
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(...)
```

It is threadsafe, so you should be able to initialize a static property for your singleton just fine.

MSDN article here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jolud/archive/2010/04/02/initialization-of-shared-resources.aspx

An example, from the ASP.NET MVC 4 standard project template.

```
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer() {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try {
                using(var context = new UsersContext()) {
                    if(!context.Database.Exists()) {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap `MyHardware` class inside a singleton with an `async` method which wrap the `SystemDiscoverer.Discovered` Event:

```
public sealed class MyHardwareSingleton
{
    static MyHardwareSingleton()
    { }

    private MyHardwareSingleton()
    { }

    private static readonly MyHardwareSingleton _myHardware = new MyHardwareSingleton();
    private SystemConnector _myConn;
    private MyHardware _mySystem;

    public MyHardwareSingleton Instance
    {
        get { return _myHardware; }
    }

    public Task<MyHardware> GetHardwareAsync()
    {
        if (_mySystem != null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_mySystem);
        }

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MyHardware>();

        SystemDiscoverer SystemDiscoverer = new SystemDiscoverer();

        SystemDiscoverer.Discovered += (sysInfo) =>
        {
            myConn = new SystemConnector(sysInfo.IPAddress);

            if (myConn != null)
            {
                mySystem = new MyHardware(myConn);
                tcs.TrySetResult(mySystem);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
            // This indicated that myConn came back null.
            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
            return tcs.Task;
        };
        // Make SystemDiscoverer run asynchrnously. We will await it so when it completes we will get the desired MyHardware instance.
        SystemDiscoverer.DiscoverAsync();
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

DiscoverAsync might be added inside the `SystemConnector` class and look like this:

```
public Task DiscoverAsync()
{
   return Task.Run(() => Discover());
}
```

And then you can call it from your code via:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var myHardware = await MyHardwareSingleton.Instance.DiscoverAsync();
}
```

Of course, i didn't handle any exception handling / cancellation. This is just a sample of what could be done using [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks promising but I'm not that familiar with the `async` methods so I'm not sure I want to use it yet...

Comment: I suggest you look into it. You can start by reading Stephan Clearys blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html
I promise you, it will save you a large amount of boilerplate code.